# .play(); is not working on HTML5 Media Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm using a small script to control HTML5 Media. The script is not working yet.

```
var $player = $( ".controls" ).prev();
var $playbutton = $(".play-button");

$($playbutton).click(function() {
    if ($($player).paused) {
        $($player).play();
    } else {
        $($player).pause();
    }
});
```

Comment: There are much errors in the code, and where is your html? What is the `$( ".controls" )` and why do you think it must play ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `$player.get(0)`

```js
var $player = $("#theVideo");
var $playbutton = $(".play-button");

$playbutton.click(function() {

  var player = $player.get(0);

  if (player.paused) {
    player.play();
  } else {
    player.pause();
  }
});
```

`.play()` is against the dom object, and not the jQuery object.